# how to define x axis at 1 instead of 0

Tags: r, scale

I have a ggplot with 7 Million values on x axis. I am trying to use scale from 1 to 7M with break at every 1 million. When I use the following code my scale never starts at 1.It will be always from 0. My first value has a index of 1. I have tried using **xlim**, **scale_x_continuous**, **coord_cartesian** and **expand_limits**. All gives x axis scale starting at 0.

Please give me suggestion.

```
scales::demo_continuous(c(1, 7000000), breaks = scales::breaks_width(1000000), labels=scales::label_number_si()) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: please, try to give a reproducible example with your question, see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`scale_x_continuous` does the trick of you precise the breaks, the labels and the limits:

```
df <- data.frame( x = sample(1:7000000,1000) )
df$y <- df$x


ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1e6,7e6,1e6),
                     labels = paste0(1:7,"M") ,
                     limits = c(1e6,7e6))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this solution. If I try to take limits starting from 1M then the values less then 1M are excluded. I want to start my scale from 1 so that the value at 1 is also plotted. how can I take scale from 1 , 500K , 1M, 1.5M, 2, 2.5M ... 7M